# Assign value in JavaScript from Php

Tags: php, jquery, openid

How to deal in jQuery with...

```
<?php
echo 'User ' . ($openid->validate() ? $openid->identity . ' has ' : 'has not ') . 'logged in.';
$data = $openid->getAttributes();
...
?>
```

I want to assign here a variable in this code in JavaScript/jQuery to check that the field is not empty.

Many thanks.

Vincent

Comment: what's is the id of the field you want to check?

Comment: which variable are you trying to pass to JS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass a PHP string to a Javascript variable (including escaping newlines)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-including-escaping-newlines)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of how you would do that.

```
var js_variable = <?php echo $php_variable ?>;
```

for a string

```
var js_variable = '<?php echo $php_variable ?>';
```

Comment: Thanks! My question was incomprehensible, but you will have fully answered!

Comment: No problem, please mark this as answered when you get the chance, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you want it to be set dynamically (by AJAX request) or statically (on page load), you have multiple options. I will show you the example for setting it on page load.

Within the appropriate `<script>` tag (on the HTML page dynamically generated by PHP) you can do something like that:

```
var myValues = <?php

    echo json_encode(array(
        'hasString' => $openid->validate() ? $openid->identity . ' has' : 'has not',
        'data' => $openid->getAttributes(),
    ));

?>;
```

and you have set what you wanted - a JS object with two properties you need.

This may look like that:

```
var myValues = {"hasString":"has not","data":"something"};
```

and if you then do this:

```
alert(myValues.hasString + ' ' + myValues.data);
```

you will receive an alert popup with the following content:

> has not something

Is it enough?